# Creating 3D surface model from Polylines, and then create/move Polylines on that surface

Tags: pyqgis, 3d

I have vector layer of Polylines. I want to build from them a 3D surface model, so then, I would be able to move some of the Polylines to better position them, or alternatively - create (draw) new Polylines.

The surface model here is important since the modified/new vertices should be taken from this model.

For the sake of simplicity we can assume linear interpolation.

(Working env. Qgis, The solution may involve programming - Python)

Comment: What kind of poly-lines do you have? Are they Iso-lines of a Digital Elevation Model?

Comment: No, they represent features on the roads.